# ¿Qué función cumple la configuración threadsafe: yes/no en el archivo app.yaml?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Estoy configurando Google App Engine para Python, en el archivo `app.yaml` existe la opción `threadsafe`.

¿En qué afecta activar/desactivar esta opción?

```
    application: blog-119911
    version: 1
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: yes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, ten en cuenta que la notación usada para configurar `threadsafe` es mediante `true` o `false`:

```
threadsafe: [true | false]
```

Google App Engine por defecto procesa las peticiones (request) en forma serial y se las envía al Web Server, sin embargo, si quisieras configurarlo para que procese las peticiones en forma paralela, usas la opción `threadsafe: true`.

Ten en cuenta que solo es requerido para aplicaciones en Python 2.7 y que el uso de `threadsafe: true` requiere también que todos los *scripts handlers* sean de tipo WSGI, es decir, cada uno de tus scripts deben estar especificados en la directiva `script` y con la notación de paquete separada por puntos:

```
application: blog-119911
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /
  script: home.app

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin
```

### Referencias:

- [Configuring with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig)
- [Required elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Required_elements)
- [Using concurrent requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Using_concurrent_requests)
- [Script handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Script_handlers)